# How to make my app run in background in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, go, service, daemon

I created a service in my Ubuntu instance by adding it to systemd like:

```
sudo systemctl enable myservice.service

Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myservice.service → /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.
```

the setting inside my myservice.service are:

```
[Unit]
Description=myserviceService

[Service]
Restart=always
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/myservice-app/core/core

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the error when I check status:

```
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: myservice.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: myservice.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: Stopped myserviceService.
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: myservice.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 02 06:51:16 myservice-ubuntu-app systemd[1]: Failed to start myservice Service.
```

What am I doing wrong? The service runs properly in foreground with no errors, its just the service that struggles to run.

Comment: can you share reproduceble code ? or try logging in your application into a file and see what exactly happening ..

Comment: Have you checked the logs? Since it's your program it should be easy to figure out why it exits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Go program is able to start normally (meaning not as a service, but manually from command line), then check if this is a policy issue.

For instance, a [SELinux policy](https://serverfault.com/a/1013293/783) could prevent your Go binary to start if it is not installed in a system path (like `/usr/local/bin`).
Or the [service definition uses relative instead of absolute paths](https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/problem-with-a-golang-webapp-and-system-service/19418) ([same here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problem-with-a-golang-webapp-and-system-service)).
Or with the [wrong user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/481835/7490).

Comment: It was a SELinux Policy, since I was trying to run my binary from `/home` rather than `/usr/local/bin` I appreciate yout quick answer